# Sharing resources in Azure Resource Manager Template

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I have multiple Azure WebApps that share the same connection strings (and app settings). I would like to refactor the below so that the config connectionstring resource is only defined once and referenced from each WebApp. Is this possible? If so, how?

```
// some sections clipped for brevity
{
  "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
  "name": "[variables('apiPortalName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/', variables('hostingPlanName'))]"
  ],
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "type": "config",
      "name": "connectionstrings",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/Sites/', variables('apiPortalName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "Default": {
          "value": "[concat('Data Source=tcp:', reference(concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('sqlServerName'))).fullyQualifiedDomainName, ',1433;Initial Catalog=', variables('settingsDatabaseName'), ';User Id=', parameters('databaseAdminLogin'), '@', variables('sqlServerName'), ';Password=', parameters('databaseAdminPassword'), ';')]",
          "type": "SQLAzure"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
},
{
  "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
  "name": "[variables('userPortalName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/', variables('hostingPlanName'))]"
  ],
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "type": "config",
      "name": "connectionstrings",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/Sites/', variables('userPortalName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "Default": {
          "value": "[concat('Data Source=tcp:', reference(concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('sqlServerName'))).fullyQualifiedDomainName, ',1433;Initial Catalog=', variables('settingsDatabaseName'), ';User Id=', parameters('databaseAdminLogin'), '@', variables('sqlServerName'), ';Password=', parameters('databaseAdminPassword'), ';')]",
          "type": "SQLAzure"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You should be able to use [variables](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authoring-templates/#variables) for that.

Comment: Sweet. I didn't know variables could be objects. Please add as answer and I will accept.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I was wrong.  You can use some functions in variable definitions, but not `reference()`.

Answer (score 0):

If your web sites are similar enough, you can create multiple sites that use a copy loop.  e.g.

```
  "variables": {
    "webSiteNameArray": ["apiPortalName", "userPortalName"]
  },

  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "[variables('webSiteNameArray')[copyIndex()]]",
          "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
          "copy": {
            "name": "webSiteLoop",
            "count": 2      
          },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/', variables('hostingPlanName'))]"
      ],
      "resources": [
        {
          "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
          "type": "config",
          "name": "connectionstrings",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Web/Sites/', variables('webSiteNameArray')[copyIndex()])]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "Default": {
              "value": "[concat('Data Source=tcp:', reference(concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('sqlServerName'))).fullyQualifiedDomainName, ',1433;Initial Catalog=', variables('settingsDatabaseName'), ';User Id=', parameters('databaseAdminLogin'), '@', variables('sqlServerName'), ';Password=', parameters('databaseAdminPassword'), ';')]",
          "type": "SQLAzure"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```